# Upgrade of GLFW 2 to 3 causing crash on vertex array generation

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I have just upgraded from GLFW 2.7 to 3.0.1. After fiddling with it to get it to work, I have run into a access violation at the call of glGenVertexArrays();

```
Graphics::Graphics():camera(*this){
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL Window", 0, 0);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
}
```

I am unsure what is wrong, as this worked before, although the code (except the gen and bind calls) was in an initialization function rather than in a constructor (as GLFW now has multi window support, although I only plan on using one).

Comment: I'm trying to guess what's happening here, so please bear with me. Have you tried setting `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` to `0`? Also, have made sure that `window` was created without any issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I realized the issue here. In GLFW 3, you need to make the context current. This is done with glfwMakeContextCurrent().